# Add and remove a Div element on click event with buttons

Tags: jquery

So basically this is the code:

HTML:

```
<button id="addHotel" type="button"> Add Hotel </button>
<div id="moreProd"> </div>
```

Jquery(version 1.7):

```
var i = 0;
$('#addHotel').click(function () {
    $("<div><div>Hotel Name:</div><div>-</div></div>").attr({
        'id': i,
        class: "addHotel"
    }).addClass('H').appendTo('#moreProd');
    i++;
});
$('#moreProd').on('click', '.H', function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Achieved: With this code i'm able to click either on Hotel Name or minus sign (-) and it will remove the whole div element.

Purpose: I don't want to click on hotel name and remove the whole div element(Hotel Name and minus sign) . I just want to click ONLY on the minus sign to remove the div (Hotel Name and minus sign together).

How do I achieve that?

Comment: You've missed the `/` in the last closing `<div>` - Guess its just a typo in the question.

Comment: if you want to trigger the click event only when minus sign is clicked and not when add hotel button , then just use the selector relevant for the minus sign.for eg if 'min' is the id set for the minus sign , then use this selector to trigger click event.if you didnt understand, then create a http://jsfiddle.net and add your relevant code there, i`ll fix it

Comment: yes it was a typo i already fixed it thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.
Add click event only on minus sign

```
var i = 0;

$('#addHotel').click(function () {
    $("<div><div>Hotel Name:</div><div class='minus'>-</div></div>").attr({
        'id': i,
        class: "addHotel"
    }).addClass('H').appendTo('#moreProd');
    i++;
});
$('.minus').on('click', '.H', function () {
    $(this).closest('.H').remove();
});
```